# implement the Select languages listed below with IF clause on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, locale

could anyone please help me out on how to implement below code for different pages on ruby on rails? For instance, the below code will change it for 'faq.html.erb' but only after it passes the If conditions.

```
<% if pageName=='faq.html.erb' %>
    <select name="Language" onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="/en/faq" selected="selected">English</option> 
        <option value="/es/faq">Español</option>
    </select>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use controller_name or request.path, for example.

```
if request.path =~ /faq/
  # ...
elsif controller_name =~ /categories/
  # ...
elsif controller_name =~ /categories/ and controller.action_name == 'index'
  # ...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, there will be a repetition of code on the each statement, is there any other way of dynamically coding it instead of hard coding?

Comment: What's not dynamic about Meduza's answer? They are just giving you some examples - you don't have to use all the code given.